# Anchor link to retina image file (srcset for anchor tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have an anchor link to an image file. (For a lightbox script for example).

```
<a href="imagefile.jpg">Click to enlarge</a>
```

Now, on retina devices I want the anchor link to lead to the retina version of the image (imagefile@2x.jpg).
Is this even possible without any script.

For the img tag there is the srcset attribute which handle this, but what for an anchor link.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this without scripting. HTML and CSS are not designed to do these things.

There are two ways to do it:

1. You can serve larger images (with 200% scale factor). They will be downscaled by a browser and displayed like retina ones. No additional code needed. However this will increase page loading time and retina-quality images will be downloaded by everyone - also people who does not have retina screens.
2. Every Lightbox does contain some scripts - for making visible the image box, switching between images on a page and other things.

   You can modify your Lightbox to look for retina versions of loading images on the server - e.g. by using `XmlHttpRequest` and sending HEAD request to server with image filename ending with `@2x`.

   Another way is to use [retina.js](https://github.com/imulus/retinajs) (~2.5KB script) which looks for DOM modifications and does that thing automatically on image loading event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will see what I do.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do this without scripting would be to link to an HTML page which contains the image using `srcset`. I guess an otherwise empty HTML page with just the `img`should get you about the same result.

It would however most probably not work with a lightbox script.